# Post Install Script - Is it possible to run as a proper user?

Tags: chatter, postinstall

I would like to create a `CollaborationGroup` when a managed package is installed. Currently I get an error

> 'INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, This user can't be added to the group.:
>   []'

when I run the following in a postInstall Script

```
     CollaborationGroup cg = new CollaborationGroup();
        cg.name = 'Lorem';
        cg.description = 'Lorem Ipsum';
        cg.collaborationType = 'Private';

        insert cg;
```

I believe this is due to the special user context the postinstall script runs under as the code works fine if run normally. Any way around this?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is not you can not run as a proper user. But you can get the Id of the user who initiated the install using

```
context.installerId()
```

My suggestion for you Chatter Group problem would be to try and set the OwnerId of the CollaborationGroup e.g

```
global class PostInstallClass implements InstallHandler {
    global void onInstall(InstallContext context) {
        CollaborationGroup cg = new CollaborationGroup(
            Name='Lorem',
            Description='Lorem Ipsum',
            CollaborationType='Private',
            OwnerId=context.installerId()
        );
        insert cg;
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I have not tested this so I don't know if it will work for sure.

Comment: Seems like this has also failed. Same error so guessing that the 'special user' is still being added as a member of the collaboration group even if the owner id is set. I've moved all of this outside of the postinstall and have created a page that finishes off the installation via an actionLink. Old Skool ways can still be the best ;)

Comment: Damn that is frustrating, you might consider logging a case with salesforce so they fix it (or won't)